# how to use different credentials inside an invoke-command

Tags: powershell

I am currently trying to get a value from a different server.  So I am connecting to a server using `$sessionUsername` and `$sessionPassword` but then I need to use different credentials to get the information that I require.

I am unsure as to how I can do this, so far I have tried to do a `Start-Job` and a `Start-Process` inside the `Invoke-Command` and even another invoker command but this has not worked.

```
$sessionUserName = "mysession"
$sessionPassword = "sessionPassword"
#$sessionUserName = "LON\user"
#$sessionPassword = "user"

$serverAddress = "the address"

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String $sessionPassword
$credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $sessionUserName,$securePassword
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $serverAddress -Credential $credentials
$username = "LON\differentuser"
$password = "different password"
$PSS = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object system.management.automation.PSCredential $username,$PSS


Invoke-Command -Session $session -scriptblock { 

    #Start-Process "C:\StuckApps\powershell.exe" -Credential $args[0] -ArgumentList "-file C:\StuckApps\connect.ps1"

    $args[0].GetNetworkCredential().username;
    $args[0].GetNetworkCredential().password;

    $t = {
        $args[0].GetNetworkCredential().username;
        $args[0].GetNetworkCredential().password;

        $conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $conn.ConnectionString = "Server = Theserver.co.uk; Database = m; Integrated Security = true;"

        $conn.Open()
        $command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
        $command.CommandTimeout = 0
        $command.CommandText = "exec dbo.AlphaBoard_GetStuckApps"
        $command.Connection = $conn
        $rows = $command.ExecuteReader()
        $dt = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
        $dt.Load($rows)
        $number = $dt.Rows.Count
        $conn.Close()
        return $number
        Write-Host "Hello"
    } 
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock $t -Credential $args[0]

    #Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList '-executionpolicy','bypass', $t -Credential $session
    $number

} -ArgumentList $cred
$number
$previousNumberPath = "C:\bamboo-home\xml-data\build-dir\INT-SAM-JOB1\number.txt"
```

The `$args[0].GetNetworkCredential().username;` inside the invoke-command shows me that this is passing the credentials in, but how can I use them? I am not sure what I am doing wrong? I can't seem to get the `$number` variable back, how can I do this?

The main problem I have is the error

> This command cannot be run due to the error: Access is denied.

Which I am unsure why this is happening as on the server itself it I run:

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -Credential $cred -ArgumentList "noexit", "-file C:\StuckApps\connect.ps1"
```

which I have also tried on my current script, it works fine, but using this on my script shows an access denied.  I have already got on the server via the first invoke-command why can't I get the same result?